# External RF interference causes monitor to blank out for 5 seconds

Tags: external-display, interference

I have an external monitor connected to a laptop by the cheapest USB-C (Thunderbolt) to DisplayPort cable I could find that was capable of 4K@60Hz.

When my house's heater switches on, the monitor goes black for approximately 5 seconds. I assume this is due to a burst of RF interference from the heating system messing with the delicate signals in my monitor cable.

It does not happen when I use a HDMI cable, but my laptop's HDMI port can't do 4K and 60Hz at the same time.

This is annoying, but not annoying enough to motivate me to build a Faraday cage around my office or to use a 30Hz display like a peasant. Is there anything else I can do about it? Are some thunderbolt cables better shielded than others?

Comment: If thunderbolt would still be fiber-based, that could have been a solution.